# Using biblatex's autopunct option for numeric style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to use biblatex's autopunct option to automatically move bracketed references inside punctuation. For example, I want `blah blah.\autocite{smith}` to render as "blah blah [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tizsV.png)." rather than "blah blah.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tizsV.png)". If I use the superscript style, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autocite=superscript,autopunct=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

Test citation inside punctuation \autocite{smith}.
Test citation outside punctuation.\autocite{smith}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, changing `autocite=superscript` to `autocite=numeric` loses the autopunct behavior:

[image]

Comment: Not the point, but at least in the MWE `autocite=numeric` will error. You can have `autocite=inline` or `autocite=plain` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this will not be possible within the framework of `biblatex`'s `autopunct` behaviour.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains the `autopunct` option thus (§3.1.2.1 Preamble Options > General, p. 50)

> This option controls whether the citation commands scan ahead for punctuation marks.

The important bit here is *scan ahead*: The `autopunct` feature can only influence punctuation that comes after the `\autocite` command.

So

```
punctuation.\autocite{sigfridsson}
```

does not fall into the scope of this feature and will never be changed. Only

```
punctuation \autocite{sigfridsson}.
```

can be changed.

---

Here is how you would implement the opposite behaviour of moving the citation after the period/outside punctuation: Use the optional `<position>` argument to `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[autocite=inline, autopunct=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}[l]{\parencite}{\parencites}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test citation inside punctuation \autocite{sigfridsson}.
Test citation outside punctuation.\autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Test citation inside punctuation.[1] Test citation outside punctuation.[1]]